# How to shift zero in the last column of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have one matrix like below-

```
A=[1 1 1 1 1;
   0 1 1 1 2;
   0 0 1 1 3]
```

But I want to place all the `0` at the end of the row, so A should be like-

```
A=[1 1 1 1 1;
   1 1 1 2 0;
   1 1 3 0 0]
```

How can I do this? Matlab experts please help me.

Comment: You want to swap all non-zero values to the left, in all rows? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go. Whole matrix, no loops, works even for non-contiguous zeros:

```
A = [1 1 1 1 1; 0 1 1 1 2; 0 0 1 1 3];

At = A.'; %// It's easier to work with the transpose
[~, rows] = sort(At~=0,'descend'); %// This is the important part.
%// It sends the zeros to the end of each column
cols = repmat(1:size(At,2),size(At,1),1);
ind = sub2ind(size(At),rows(:),cols(:));
sol = repmat(NaN,size(At,1),size(At,2));
sol(:) = At(ind);
sol = sol.'; %'// undo transpose
```

As usual, for Matlab versions that do not support the `~` symbol on function return, change `~` by a dummy variable, for example:

```
[nada, rows] = sort(At~=0,'descend'); %// This is the important part.
```

Comment: Love the no-looping solution. I was trying to figure out a way to avoid loops, but you beat me to it. Very nice.

Comment: I am using Matlab 7.8.0.Here "~" sign not working.showing error message "Error: File: com_all.m Line: 26 Column: 3
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [."

Comment: Somehow it dawned on me that `sort` could do the trick. It critically relies on the fact that "When more than one element has the same value, the order of the elements are preserved in the sorted result" as per the documentation

Comment: @user2663126 For 7.8.0, if "~" does not work, replace that line by "[nada, rows]..."

Comment: I guess my solution was just too simple :P

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus If "too" means "using loops", then yes :-)

Comment: I tried your solution and I get the equivalent of `fliplr(A)` ??

Comment: @TryHard How can that be? Considering the third row for example, my solution gives 1 1 3 0 0 (as it should), whereas `fliplr(A)` gives 3 1 1 0 0

Comment: @LuisMendo  I really don't know, but I get a different result from you. In any case I was inspired by your answer and posted my own below.

Answer (score 4):

A more generic example:

```
A = [1 3 0 1 1;
     0 1 1 1 2;
     0 0 1 1 3]

% Sort columns directly
[~,srtcol] = sort(A == 0,2);
% Sorted positions 
sz  = size(A);
pos = bsxfun(@plus, (srtcol-1)*sz(1), (1:sz(1))'); % or use sub2ind
```

The result

```
B = A(pos)
B =
     1     3     1     1     0
     1     1     1     2     0
     1     1     3     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways to do this. one fast way can be easily like this:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 0 5 7 0];

idx=(find(a==0));

idx =

     5     8

b=a;   % save a new copy of the vector
b(idx)=[];    % remove zero elements

b =

     1     2     3     4     5     7

c=[b zeros(size(idx))]

c =

     1     2     3     4     5     7     0     0
```

You may modify this code as well.

Comment: But that's just for a single row

Comment: the same can be done for matrices, you may need to modify the last part.

Answer (score 1):

If your zeros are always together, you could use the [`circshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) command. This shifts values in an array by a specified number of places, and wraps values that run off the edge over to the other side. It looks like you would need to do this separately for each row in `A`, so in your example above you could try:

```
A(2,:) = circshift(A(2,:), [1 -1]);    % shift the second row one to the left with wrapping
A(3,:) = circshift(A(3,:), [1 -2]);    % shift the third row two to the left with wrapping
```

In general, if your zeros are always at the front of the row in `A`, you could try something like:

```
for ii = 1:size(A,1)                              % iterate over rows in A
    numShift = numel(find(A(ii,:) == 0));         % assuming zeros at the front of the row, this is how many times we have to shift the row.
    A(ii,:) = circshift(A(ii,:), [1 -numShift]);  % shift it
end
```

Comment: May be you cannot understand my point.My                                A=[1 1 1 1 1; 0 1 1 1 2; 0 0 1 1 3] but i want                        A=[1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 2 0; 1 1 3 0 0] .it means all the "o" are in last.

Comment: Did you try what I wrote? That does shift all of the zeros so that they are at the end of their row. The output of those first two lines is `[1 1 1 2 0]` and `[1 1 3 0 0]` respectively.

Comment: @user2663126 Sorry, _now_ it is working properly. This works if all you want to do is shift your numbers to the left, although it could be improved if you could avoid the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (just a fast hack):

```
for row_k = 1:size(A, 1)
   [A_sorted, A_sortmap] = sort(A(row_k, :) == 0, 'ascend');

   % update row in A:    
   A(row_k, :) = A(row_k, A_sortmap);
end
```

Now optimized for versions of MATLAB not supporting `~` as garbage lhs-identifier.

Comment: Too fast a hack apparently - forgot to test properly :-) Try it again, with the new correction.

Comment: I am using Matlab 7.8.0.Here "~" sign not working.showing error message "Error: File: com_all.m Line: 26 Column: 3
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [."

Comment: Well ... then you just replace ~ with a variable that you do not use afterwards. Perhaps use `ans` or `dummy`. Or `A_sorted`.

Answer (score 1):

@LuisMendo's answer is inspiring in its elegance, but I couldn't get it to work (perhaps a matlab version thing). The following (based on his answer) worked for me:

```
Aaux = fliplr(reshape([1:numel(A)],size(A)));
Aaux(find(A==0))=0;
[Asort iso]=sort(Aaux.',1,'descend');
iso = iso + repmat([0:size(A,1)-1]*size(A,2),size(A,2),1);
A=A.';
A(iso).'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also asked this question and got a super elegant answer (non of above answers is same) here:
[Optimize deleting matrix leading zeros in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775709/optimize-deleting-matrix-leading-zeros-in-matlab)