# take from matrix non-zero rows per column

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A`. Suppose it is:

```
A=[1 0 8; 
   0 0 2; 
   3 0 5; 
   4 8 0; 
   0 5 3;
   6 1 3;
   1 6 5;
   0 7 1]
```

and I want to get the non-zero rows subscripts per column in a new matrix.
In my example that will be,

```
B = [ 1 3 4 6 7 0 0 0; 
      4 5 6 7 8 0 0 0; 
      1 2 3 5 6 7 8 0]
```

In terms of just size, if `A=(m,n)`, `B` will be `B=(n,m)` (the transpose). In terms of content, `B` contains the subscripts of the non-zero rows in `A` as described above.

Comment: you want to transpose the matrix like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose ? if so just do B = A'

Comment: is your example correct? it doesn't suite the question you wrote

Comment: You may need to explain better how you get B from A.  There may be some typos, but they don't seem to be related.

Comment: i do not want to transpose

Comment: the first column of A has in rows 1,3,4,6,7 non-zero element

Comment: my example was WRONG i correct it, thank you

Comment: so basically you want to apply `sort` to each column, but move zeros to the end?

Comment: i correct it , A has 8 rows and B has 8 columns

Comment: i think sort will sort the numbers in matrix, i do not care about the value but for the number of the row that has the non-zero value

Comment: @user3071587 Did you get an answer that you needed? With your test data, my answer below does what you need and is fast and concise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
mask = ~sort(~A);     %// destination of row indexes in output
[ii,~]=find(A);       %// get the row indexes
B = zeros(size(A));
B(mask) = ii; B=B.'   %'//write indexes to output and transpose
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want (get the non-zero row indices per column). It's very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151296/how-to-shift-zero-in-the-last-column-of-a-matrix/):

```
[r c] = size(A);
M = bsxfun(@times, A~=0, 1:size(A,2)).'; %'// substitute values by indices
[~, rows] = sort(M~=0,'descend'); %//'' push zeros to the end
cols = repmat(1:r,c,1);
ind = sub2ind([c r],rows(:),cols(:));
B = repmat(NaN,c,r);
B(:) = M(ind).';
B = B.';
```

Result:

```
>> B

B =

     1     3     4     6     7     0     0     0
     4     5     6     7     8     0     0     0
     1     2     3     5     6     7     8     0
```

Comment: Wowzers, that was quite a showing in that question you referenced!  It was before my time at SO, sadly.  Anyway, I'd agree with TryHard that your answer is indeed "inspiring in its elegance".  ;) +1

Comment: @chappjc Very nice words! Thanks! It was one of my first answers; it's taken me quite a while to find it now :-)

Comment: Hmm, I like the `//` commenting workaround for SO's poor MATLAB formatting, although a `'` still messes with it.

Comment: @chappjc So is it the `'` that spoils it? I noticed that it gets wrong sometimes, but I never knew exactly what it was.

Comment: Yeah, ever notice an extra `'` in my comments after a line of code (actually, see my current answer)? That's to trick the highlighting into stopping the string color.

Comment: Yes, just noticed that up here! Good to know!

Comment: @chappjc Looks like the number of `'` has to balance that to the left of the `%`